# Multiple Join from single Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have the following query:

```
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock p
ON sig.label = p.Value
union
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock q
ON sig.proces = q.Value
union
select [signaleringid], label,  proces,  product from Signalering sig
JOIN ScreeningProductAuthorizationLock r
ON sig.product = r.Value
```

How can I achieve the same result without repeating 3 times the same Select query? What I want is 1 select query only, from which I join separately to 3 different tables but at the end the results are all together.

EDIT:

```
Signalering table: [label][proces][product]
ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock table: [Value][Lock]
ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock: [Value][Lock]
ScreeningProductAuthorizationLock: [Value][Lock]
```

Comment: If the relationship between these tables is 1 to N, then you can't rewrite this query to avoid writing 3 selects. Maybe you can use a CTE or a subquery to apply filters and/or expressions once, but the joins must be on 3 different selects or you will multiply the amount of rows depending on the cardinality of their relationships.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, sorry! Done!

Comment: UNION ALL in the screening tables in a subquery, then JOIN sig.

Comment: @jarlh can you show me please?

Comment: A bit tricky since I don't know which tables the different columns belong to... Qualify _all_ columns, just like `sig.product`.

Comment: Edit your question and qualify your column names, so we know what the table looks like.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM signalering s where exists(...) or exists(...) or exists(...)`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid writing the select 3 times? Each one joins with different columns and tables and they are simple enough on their own.

Answer (score 0):

As you only use columns from the table `Signalering` you don't need to use join to get this result. One solution is to check if the given value exists in the corresponding table. Then combine the exist expressions with an or statement in the where clause. In this way you will only get Signalering rows which will fulfill one or more of the exists expressions.

```
select sig.[signaleringid], sig.label,  sig.proces,  sig.product 
from Signalering sig
where sig.label exists (select Value from ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock)
or sig.proces exists (select Value from ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock)
or sig.product exists (select Value from ScreeningProductAuthorizationLock)
group by sig.[signaleringid], sig.label,  sig.proces,  sig.product
```

One other option could be to use left outer join

```
select sig.[signaleringid], sig.label,  sig.proces,  sig.product 
from Signalering sig
left outer join ScreeningLabelAuthorizationLock la on sig.label = la.Value
left outer join ScreeningProcessAuthorizationLock lp on sig.proces = lp.Value
left outer join ScreeningProductAuthorizationLock lpa on sig.product = lpa.Value
group by sig.[signaleringid], sig.label,  sig.proces,  sig.product
```

Comment: But I still see 3 times the same query in your answer (select sig.* from Signalering sig)

Comment: Thanks first of all! But.. the syntax is invalid, I think you meant to use the "in" condition instead of "exists". But apart from that, is there no way to use multiple JOIN instead of all these Select ?

Comment: @Tarta which db are you using? "In" is slower then "exists" but it will do the same thing here.

Comment: I am using Sql Server. Unfortunately the second query shows different results than the first one.. The first one is correct so far though